# Three coupled differential equations to be solved analytically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have three coupled DEs, two first order and the third partial second order with laplacian operator

[image]

$\lambda, \beta$ and $V$ are constants. Any advice on how to approach the problem analytically would be a huge help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You should also mention that these are partial differential equations, and that the second order derivative operator is of Laplacian or elliptical type. What do you imagine under "matrix solution"?

Comment: @LutzL made the edits as suggested

Answer (score 0):

The three partial differential equations (PDEs) are
\begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{\partial \theta_h}{\partial x} + \beta_h (\theta_h - \theta_w) &=& 0,\\
  \frac{\partial \theta_c}{\partial y} + \beta_c (\theta_c - \theta_w) &=& 0,\\
  \lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2} + \beta_h (\theta_h - \theta_w) + V \beta_c (\theta_c - \theta_w) &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
(MathJax allows you to use LaTeX expressions in your posts).

These are *linear PDEs with constant coefficients.* Using the first two PDEs you can write $\theta_h$ and $\theta_c$ using $\theta_w$:
\begin{equation}
 \theta_h(x,y) = \beta_h e^{-\beta_h x} \int e^{\beta_h x} \theta_w(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}x, \quad \theta_c(x,y) = \beta_c e^{-\beta_c y} \int e^{\beta_c y} \theta_w(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}y
\end{equation}
(keyword *integrating factor*).

Replacing $\theta_h, \theta_c$ by these expressions in the third PDE yields a single *linear partial integro-differential equation (PIDE)* for $\theta_w$, which can probably be solved using some Fourier or Laplace transform technique.

Comment: Thanks for the help . I will try this approach. Also, will put the effort to use MathJax from now.

Answer (score 0):

@Christoph After your suggestions the equation takes the following form

\begin{eqnarray}
  \lambda_h \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial x^2} + \lambda_c V \frac{\partial^2 \theta_w}{\partial y^2} +( -\beta_h - V \beta_c )\theta_w +\beta_h^2 e^{-\beta_h x} \int e^{\beta_h x} \theta_w(x,y)  \mathrm{d}x + \beta_c^2 e^{-\beta_c y}\int e^{\beta_c y} \theta_w(x,y)\mathrm{d}y = 0
\end{eqnarray}

Although you did refer to the use of Laplace and Fourier transfom to solve the resulting PIDE, can you point to any reference where I could find examples analogous to such equations ? I tried some textbooks ( *Partial differential equations, Harumi & Hattori* ; *A Journey into partial Differential equations, Bray*) on PDE but they normally won't cover PIDEs.